# Select right label for x axis in case of Multiindex dataframe with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

First of all merry x-mas to you all :). Hope you are doing well and relaxing.
But as you can see, some people have to work. And there is the point where I need your help :)

I do have an very messy csv chart with many data which I handeled to clean and to make it easier to read and to work with. But now I am stuck.

I created a multiindex with level=0 as date and level=1 for time and column c as attribute, as you can see on the image

I would like to plot this information, with date on the x axis and the attreibute on the y-axis. However, I stuck here:

```
BMW_Clean_Data.loc["07.07.2018"::,]["Atteibute"].plot()
```

If I plot this I get the following

As you can see guys, on the x axis I get Date and time format. How can I select only date, or time as x axis?

I am grateful for any kind of help
[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide a small sample of data to test your solution

Comment: It is a very large csv file. That is why I selected the region of interest. All I am interested is: Reduce the dimension for x axis labelling from date, time to date

Comment: The csv table has 27 columns which is why I reduced it to the screenshot above :)